# How to store data between activities in android?, shopping cart like

Tags: android

I want to make some data available between some activities, just like a shopping cart on a website would do.

This data would probably be a collection of strings maybe a list, a map or something like that. Each item should have associated a id, quantity, type, and a text note (about last one isn't sure yet)

The point is that it doesn't need to be persistent after session ends, and this data will be deleted and recreated completely many times in a whole session.

**The question is :**
Is the best choice to use a SharedPreferences?, a database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even better choice would be some singleton java collection ( map or list ) located via factory object.  Just store your cart there and do not bother with database or preferences at all

In case you decide to use preferences, I can recomment my small databinding library:

https://github.com/ko5tik/andject

Comment: Usually this is the solution I go with in addition to storing any data I want to be sure to keep in a database or shared preferences.

Comment: Do you mean to create a class with a collection of custom objects?

Comment: You could do that, or you could just have your Collection stored in the Application Object (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

Comment: Application singleton is great but you have to manage it since it will not go away once the Activity is done with it

Comment: Piece of cake - config activity forces save on pause

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is to use a class with public static variables declared and jus set them from any activity and the retrieve that saved value in any other activity just by calling through a static refrence i.e MyContantsClass.StaticVar1 like

```
class MySessionVars
 {
      public static int MyVar1;
 }
```

In first Activity

```
{
   MySessionVars.NyVar1=10;
}
```

and from any other activity

```
{
    Var = MySessionVars.NyVar1;
}
```

this is easiest way and will retain vars untill app is closed

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) (by Google) to send and receive any data btw activities, even class object.

---

**Send:** (FirstActivity)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Gson gson = new Gson();
intent.putExtra("CustomClassObject", gson.toJson(object));
startActivity(intent);
```

---

**Receive:** (SecondActivity)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) 
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        CustomClass object = gson.fromJson(extras.getString("CustomClassObject"), CustomClass.class);
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) or Intent.

I wouldn't recommend using database for this purpose.  Database needs to be properly opened and closed.  Where data is passed around activities, it can get messy which activity should be the last to close the database, and may cause a leak.  If you are just passing these data from one Activity to another, create a Bundle, attach it to Intent as you start the next activity.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences are key-value pairs whereas database in Android is SQLite both persists after session. You can do any number of operations on SQLite database and use the same file during next session also. 
You can put up comments to my answers if you need more clarifications for your particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences is great for storing simple key/value pairs and small amounts of data, however, I imagine your shopping cart object(s) might be a bit more complicated than that. For that reason I would probably use a SQLite database. If you don't have complicated data though, and you just want to store some simple stuff then Shared Preferences should do.

Answer (score 0):

People may talk about making global data or storing values in sharedpreference but according to my experience, the simplest way is to just create a separate class with your variables or arraylists declared as public static then use them throughout your project by just referring to the classname.variable name.
`class global`

```
{
   public static arrayList<String> my;
}
```

in any of your activity
global.my

This is the simplest method i found so far!